Vietname Ho Chi Minh city to Hanoi train
How to book and take a sleeper train from Ho Chi Minh city to Hanoi?

Booking
Booked the 1st class slepper at 12go Ho Chi Minh City to Hanoi online. The train SE4 leaving Ho Chi Minh at 19:00 from the Saigon Railway Station. There are several empty cabins and my cabin was only me. Perhaps, the train leaving late may not be so busy.

Initially booked SE6 leaving at 3PM but they informed the train had been booked out. Please note that that you made the booking on the site does not mean it is actually booked.

From: 12Go Support 2384188@s.12go.asia
Subject: Booking #**** Ho Chi Minh City - Hanoi
Unfortunately the tickets you selected have been sold out on your departure date (seat sold out). May we suggest alternative option: Move to 2nd class sleeper. Could you please advise if the option is suitable to you so we will process your booking. Please note that tickets subject to availability at the time of processing and there are limited tickets left at the moment. We apologize for the hassle. Look forward to your reply
Best regards,
Tiim Manager.
Email: vn@12go.asia

Getting to the Saigon railway station
Address 1 D. Nguyen Thong, Ward 9, District 3, Ho Chi Minh City, Vietnam.

Road congestion can be quite heavy especially when people are going home from work. Bikes pushing into a junction regardless with the signals blocking each other can cause significant delay. Take enough time.
Food in the train
Some articles said there was no food serving, but in my case, food services went back and forth a few times a day. However, bring food and water just in case. Especially, water.
Toilet
Some reported it smells but it was not bad at all. There is a door between the toilet location and the cabin compartment. However, this is in Vietnam. We cannot expect it is like a sleeper train in Europe. Bring your toilet paper just in case. To take a distance from the toilet, I booked a cabin located in the middle of the train.
Cabin

Bed

Air condition
Air condition is always on and quite chilly for me, especially during the night. Bring a jacket to keep you warm.
 
Power
There is a 220V power supply in a cabin.

Lock

Announcement
They announce arrival to each station in English as well. But, the train crew does not speak English.

It seems more a review, and why did you ask a question and quickly answer to it in so much detailed manner?  Are you related (or take advantage) with people in the first link?

@GiacomoCatenazzi self-answers are welcome on SE, and 12go.asia is a well-known site. "Please note that that you made the booking on the site does not mean it is actually booked." is a good tip
